# Changing the rendered area's rectangle inside Electron's BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to implement a conditionally shown additional view in my Electron app, that would appear on the bottom of the `BrowserWindow`. Think of it like a virtual keyboard.

I use the `BrowserView` class and attach it to the window like that:

```js
view = new BrowserView({
    nodeIntegration: true,
});

win.setBrowserView(view);
view.setBounds({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 0, // initially hidden
    height: 0,
});
view.webContents.loadURL('https://example.com');
return view;
```

This creates a "hidden" `BrowserView` that loads in the background and can then be shown programmatically:

```js
const height = 300;
const size = win.getSize();
view.setBounds({
    x: 0,
    y: size[1] - height,
    width: size[0],
    height,
});
```

It shows the view perfectly, although it covers a part of the page below and I'm unable to even scroll there. I'd like to resize the original content by shrinking it's `height` accordingly to the view's height (300px in this case), so that the two are rendered next to each other and not overlap.

I tried using `setContentSize(width, height)` method of the `BrowserWindow` as well as `setBounds`, but they both resize the whole window, not just the rendered area.

Is there any other way to do this? Ultimately I could use an approach like this:

```
BrowserWindow: 1920x1080
   BrowserView(content): 1920x780 X:0 Y:0
   BrowserView(additional): 1920x300 X:0 Y:780
```

And alter the bounds of both views at once when showing the additional one.

But wont this worsen the performance, since I guess it will actually end up as 3 separate webview instances, just that `BrowserWindow` will have an empty webview rendered?